# How to store large amounts of text and retain versioning?

Tags: text

Any tips on how to store large amounts of text, such as programming code. So I need to retain the tabs, spaces, etc?

Also how could i keep versions like say someone edits one line, i can see the changes that have been made?

Comment: Whitespace in code is kind of important for the programmers. Anyone who says otherwise should be given only minified Javascript to work with.

Answer (score 3):

That's what various revision control systems are for.

Any of [git](http://git-scm.com/), [cvs](http://nongnu.org/cvs/), [rcs](http://www.gnu.org/s/rcs/), [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and a [host of others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) will work.

Comment: but i dont want something like that, i want to develop something myself that is simpler.

Comment: If the proposed solution does not fit your constraints, you need to explain *what* your constraints are. Also, reinventing the wheel is unlikely to end well: you'll likely spend too much time to arrive at a buggy solution that will not handle some of your future needs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other posters that you probably want to use what has already been done.  Sometimes rolling your own can be fun.

You could write a wrapper for the command line diff utils.  Each user could have their own config to choose their preferred editor.  The script would made a copy of the file, so you would have an orig and new.  When done editing the script would kick off a diff and store that to disk and delete the original backup of the file.  This way, you would only store the latest versions plus all diffs so you can revert back and also see the changes.

I would keep a log of all diffs created and tag them in a csv with the userid of the person who modified the file and the timestamp of the modification.